# python ursina engine does not render the window

Tags: python-3.x, ursina

Here is the code that I wrote.

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()

player = FirstPersonController()

app.run()
```

It is not a lot, but for some reason the window does not show up properly:
[image]

EDIT:
I use python -v 3.10 and ursina -v 4.1.1
My operating system is windows 10

EDIT 2:
It doesn't work on python -v 3.7 either

Comment: There's nothing in your world, have you tried adding content like a simple cube? Also, the FirstPersonController needs a ground to run on so that may not be the best choice.

Comment: Can it be because of screen resolution?

Comment: its not a screen resolution problem nor is it a problem with empty scene

Comment: Maibe try with python 3.9, or use the GitHub version of Ursina.

Answer (score 1):

it works properly for me. there is some ways to fix that:

- uninstall and reinstall Ursina
- make ground for the player for example write:

```py
ground = Entity(model='plane', texture='white_cube', collider='box')
```